# How properly get the style made by blend in code behind (windows phone)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7.1, blend

I made the style in blend which looks like this and is keeped in xaml side of this screen, it's looks like this:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="TopinsStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFEA1616"/>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledContent">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledContent">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="EnabledBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="EnabledContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledBackground" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="DisabledContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I need to add the `togglebuttons` dynamically and here is the part of code

```
foreach(dbDodatki z in choosenMeal.id_of_ingredients_object)
{
    ToggleButton tg = new ToggleButton();
    tg.Name = z.Ingredient_name_pl_pl;
    tg.Content = z.Ingredient_name_pl_pl;
    tg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,22,65,38));
    tg.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    tg.Style = App.Current.Resources["TopinsStyle"] as Style;
    tg.IsChecked = true;
    wrapWithBtns.Children.Add(tg);
}
```

but the way I add the style doesn't work. I couldn't find any other way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you put the resource in PhoneApplicationPage's resources, but you are trying to pull it from the application reources.

Either put your style in the Application resources (App.xaml for a wpf application, don't know about a windows phone app), or reference the correct resources.

Assuming the code behind is in PhoneApplicationPage, it should be:

```
tg.Style = this.Resources["TopinsStyle"] as Style;
```